# Zabbix mqtt json и формат лога

Tags: json, zabbix, mqtt

Как преобразовать json такого вида

```
{
"mqtt/topic/dev" : "{\"data\":{...}}"
}
```

в

```
{
"mqtt/topic/dev" : {"data":{...}}
}
```